# Is there a way to download the Apache C++ Standard Library User Guide?

Tags: c++, apache, stl, download, user-guide

I couldn't find a download-to-print version of the [Apache C++ Standard Library User Guide](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/index.html) anywhere - the only options available are the frames and no-frames versions online. Writing a script to wget and collate them seems overkill.

Does anyone know if a downloadable-to-print PDF or other formats exist - and if not, why not?

**PS** - I realize that downloading the stdcxx lib will give me the html files - but its still limited to the browser. I'd like to print the docs out as a ready reference.

Comment: Do you have a print-to-PDF capability?  A page-at-a-time layout though is less than ideal for that.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe acrobat can convert a web site to PDF.
http://www.abdn.ac.uk/webpack/factsheet5.shtml

You can also get a trial copy from http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/tryout.html?promoid=DTELN